# running docker in sysbox runtime connected to the specifc network

Tags: linux, docker, docker-network, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run the docker in [sysbox](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox) runtime on ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance.
The docker has to connected to the specific network.
`sudo docker run --runtime=sysbox-runc --network=mynetwork -it -d mydocker start.sh`
I am getting the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:425: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:607: container init caused: switching Docker DNS: rootfs_linux.go:1385: writing /etc/resolv.conf caused: open /etc/resolv.conf: permission denied: unknown.
```

When I do not specify the network in docker run command, the docker is started as expected. So I can investigate what happens inside with /etc/resolv.conf:

```
root@bf26ac9a77cd:/# findmnt /etc/resolv.conf
TARGET           SOURCE                                                                                                                  FSTYPE OPTIONS
/etc/resolv.conf /dev/nvme0n1p1[/var/lib/docker/containers/bf26ac9a77cd8cd1386d0b699614143aa6196092e06723d09649b979266bddf9/resolv.conf] ext4   rw,relatime,discard

root@bf26ac9a77cd:/# ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 607 Aug 29 06:52 /etc/resolv.conf

root@bf26ac9a77cd:/# touch /etc/resolv.conf
touch: cannot touch '/etc/resolv.conf': Permission denied
```

This sounds reasonable from perspective of the environment isolation. But how can I connect the docker to the certain network?

Comment: what is the network driver used to make the network mynetwork

Answer (score 0):

Sysbox needs to write into the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` during initialization. It is unable to write into `/etc/resolv.conf` due to the `nobody:nogroup` file attributes. This happens due to lack of Shiftfs or the newer ID-mapped-mounts kernel feature.

D-mapped-mounts requires kernel >= 5.12; in my case it was 5.11

Shiftfs can be installed (it's a kernel module). [The instructions here](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox/blob/master/docs/user-guide/install-package.md#installing-shiftfs).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).